# Remove column from insert or update in Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have Doctrine 2 Entity mapped to Oracle DB table, and this table has an auto generated ID column by some trigger, so I want to do insert data without the ID column, how can I make it something like read only column? i.e. not including it in the insert?
I know I can do a custom generate strategy for ID, but I just want it to be handled by the DB, and I want to be able to read it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try mapping your field as following?

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;
```

This will tell the ORM to use the inserted row's values to fill the `$id` in your object.

Comment: thanks for you response, the problem I have is with the insert in oracle table, the documentation on http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html says "This strategy does currently not provide full portability and is supported by the following platforms: MySQL/SQLite (AUTO_INCREMENT), MSSQL (IDENTITY) and PostgreSQL (SERIAL)." and I don't want doctrine to include the ID in the insert, it will be filled by a trigger... maybe a sequence or anything else... I hope I make my question clear now... any help?

Comment: First of all, use "latest" for docs.

Since I don't use Oracle DB, you may just write a small integration test around this use case. I think `IDENTITY` should work with your problem.

Comment: Aha... it worked fine... thanks... 
may be the documentation should be changed... :)

Comment: Ocramius: can you please see this related isssue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741030/doctrine-2-cascade-persist-oracle-identity-is-returning-0-as-last-inserted-id