# Doctrine 2: cascade persist Oracle "IDENTITY" is returning 0 as last inserted ID

Tags: oracle, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using doctrine 2 with oracle, the tables in the database has some triggers that generate the IDs, and my ID mapping of my tables is like the following:

```
/**
 * @orm\Id
 * @orm\Column(type="integer");
 * @orm\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;
```

and I have a OneToMany relation, with `cascade={"persist"}` but it is not working, I tried the same code with MySQL and it is working fine, but in oracle the last insert Id seems to always return 0 instead of the real id of the inserted row... and so the cascade persist is not working... is this a bug in doctrine or am I doing something wrong? any help?

After following the code it seems that the method

`Doctrine\ORM\Id\IdentityGenerator::generate`

is returning 0, I don't know why it is being invoked since the `sequenceName` is null (there is no sequence in the deffinition!

**EDIT: Here are the entities:**
The Client Entity:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients")
 **/
class Client {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="name",type="string",length=255,unique=true) */
    protected $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ContactInformation", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist"})
    **/
    protected $contactInformations;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->contactInformations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getContactInformations() {
        return $this->contactInformations;
    }

    public function addContactInformations(Collection $contactInformations)
    {
        foreach ($contactInformations as $contactInformation) {
            $contactInformation->setClient($this);
            $this->contactInformations->add($contactInformation);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $tags
     */
    public function removeContactInformations(Collection $contactInformations)
    {
        foreach ($contactInformations as $contactInformation) {
            $contactInformation->setClient(null);
            $this->contactInformations->removeElement($contactInformation);
        }
    }

    public function setContactInformations($contactInformations) {
        $this->contactInformations = $contactInformations;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The Contact Information Entity:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact_informations")
 **/
class ContactInformation {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ContactInformationType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $type;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="text") */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="contact_informations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $client;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getClient() {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function setClient($client = null) {
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code (especially the mappings) of both entities?

Comment: @Jasper I just added the entities in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support auto incrementing, so you cannot use the "IDENTITY" strategy in Doctrine. You'll have to use the "SEQUENCE" (or "AUTO") strategy.

When specifying "AUTO", Doctrine will use "IDENTITY" for MySql and "SEQUENCE" for Oracle.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies

Comment: I know that, but I am using triggers to auto generate the ID, if I use "AUTO" then Doctrine will try to find a sequence to get the ID value, and this is not my case, in my case the ID is generated using trigger (most of the time a trigger with a sequence), and I don't want doctrine to take care of generating the ID...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any Oracle experience, so unfortunately cannot give you a better answer.

Comment: I have proposed a solution for this here 

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-563

maybe you want to check it and help with that :)