# Doctrine 2: Oracle Insert Trigger

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

i currently started to work with the symfony2 framework and doctrine2.

I have the following problem here with using doctrine when I want to insert an object.

Following given situation:

- The table uses a sequence, that generates the ID via BEFORE INSERT
  Trigger
- The sequence is uses by other tables as well, so there is no name
  convention like: $table->getName() . '_SEQ'; (see
  Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/OraclePlatform.php getIdentitySequenceName())
- The sequence that should be uses id called: general_data_seq
- The design of the tables and triggers is given and cannot be changed.

I have made the following entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 *
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

     /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

If i want to save this using doctrine like this

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$test = new Test();
$test->setName('Max');

$em->persist($test);
$em->flush();
```

I'm getting the message:

> ORA-02289: sequence does not exist.

What is true, since the sequence that should be use really does not exist.

My question now is: How to use docrine here so that the persisted entity has the inserted id generated by the trigger?

I found a related problem here: 
[Doctrine 2: cascade persist Oracle "IDENTITY" is returning 0 as last inserted ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741030/doctrine-2-cascade-persist-oracle-identity-is-returning-0-as-last-inserted-id)
and here: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/1772

but nighter of them helped me to find a solution, since they are still bases on using the table-named-sequence.

Comment: To avoid you a serious headache: Only use Doctrine ORM if it "owns" the schema.